# How to get users of Exchange server by Distinguished name using LDAP in notes directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, distinguishedname

I am trying to get Distinguished name of users from exchange `server` in notes using `LDAP` to set `bearbeiter` field,so no one will have access on that particular document except the users which are added in `bearbeiter` field.I have tried other types of names like `cannonical` or `abbreviated` but that dosen't work. How can i get `Distinguished name(DN)` name of exchange users?

```
public String lookup(String searchedName) throws NotesException {
      Vector<String> result = new Vector<String>();
      String result = null;
      try {
              Session sess = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession();
              Directory dir = sess.getDirectory();
              dir.setSearchAllDirectories(true);
              Vector<String> itemsToFetch = new Vector<String>();
              itemsToFetch.add("FullName");
              itemsToFetch.add("Mail");
              Vector<String> namesToLookup = new Vector<String>(); 
              namesToLookup.add(searchedName);   
                          DirectoryNavigator dirnav = dir.lookupNames("($Users)",namesToLookup, itemsToFetch, true); 
                          int count = 0;
                 while (dirnav.isNameLocated()) {   
                     while (dirnav.isMatchLocated()) {
                         Vector<String> iv = dirnav.getNthItemValue(1);                     
                         String notesid =iv.get(0) ;                               
                         result=notesid;
                         dirnav.findNextMatch();
                         count += 1;
                              }
                              dirnav.findNextName();
                          }
                          dirnav.recycle();
                          dir.recycle();
                          sess.recycle();                                         
              return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("In Catch, error in lookup function inside DirectoryDelegatesPickerEws java class "+e.getStackTrace());  
          return result;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Show us some code that shows what you have tried already